# Speed up Delete rows between dates based on cells in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a routine that works but seems to take long. Basically I want to delete any row in the sheet "data" column C that does not fall in the range of the two dates I input in sheet "Dashboard" start date H13 and end date H14

```
Sub dateDelete()
Sheets("Data").Select
Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "C"    '<=== change to suit
Dim i As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim dteStart As Date
Dim dteEnd As Date

    dteStart = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("H13")
    dteEnd = Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("H14")

    With Application
    '    .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    With ActiveSheet

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1

            If .Cells(i, "C").Value < dteStart Or .Cells(i, "C").Value > dteEnd Then

                .Rows(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i

    End With

    With Application

        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an autofilter to identify the rows to remove.

```
With ActiveSheet
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode= false
    with .range(.cells(1, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
        .autofilter field:=1, criteria1:="<"&dteStart, criteria2:=">"&dteEnd , operator:=xlor
        with .resize(.rows.count-1, 1).offset(1, 0)
            if cbool(application.subtotal(103, .cells)) then
                .cells.entirerow.delete
            end if
        end with
    end with
    if .autofiltermode then .autofiltermode= false
end with
```

Comment: It seems to delete everything

Comment: I had another look and it appears I should have used xlOr rather than xlAnd.